# How to remove the last comma on a number , and bug with decimals?

Tags: c

I wrote the code, I'm learning array, how can it not print my last comma on the numbers, and how does it load this decimal for me properly?

input n: `7`
numbers: `7 1 0 2.1 -2 5 7 3`
output: `{-2,0,1,2,3,5,7,}`
output which I need: `{-2,0,1,2.1,3,5,7}`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, a;
    float n;
    float num[100];
    printf("Input number n: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    while (n < 1) {
        printf("Wrong input!\n");
        printf("Input numbers array: \n");
        scanf("%f", &n);
    }
    printf("Input %g number: \n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) {
                a = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n{");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%g,", num[i]);
    }
    printf("}");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By printing the first element separately with `"\n{%g"` and then loop from `1` with `",%g"` (or variations on that).

Comment: You use `n` to store the number of numbers and also each number (temporarily) ?  I can't guess what you try to do at all, please, edit your code and try to use different variable names for different things, which will improve your code readability and make better our understanding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the **i486** answer and to solve the decimal part problem, you must be aware that by declaring

```
int a
```

whenever you do

```
a = num[i]
```

you are 'converting' num[i] to integer and therefore you lose the decimal part.

that's why it must be

```
float a
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf( "%g%s", num[i], i == n - 1 ? "" : "," );
```

Method 2:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        printf( "%g,", num[i] );
}
printf("%g}", num[n - 1]);
```

Method 3: (after **nielsen** comment)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf( i ? ",%g" : "%g", num[i] );
```

Comment: I have some bug and with the decimal it shows me 2 instead of 2.1 where ad I fix it @i486

Comment: IMHO it gives slightly cleaner code to print a comma before all numbers except the first one.